# SQL Result to excel file

Tags: windows, sql

In Microsoft SQL Service Management Studio, there is an option to send results to file when a query is executed.

Is it possible for that result to be changed to excel format?

Are there other ways to turn results into excel format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to have the Output format for Text Results set to “Comma delimited”. 
Excel can easily open it just by clicking on the file name of the CSV file.

The menu path is Query -> Query Options then click on “Text” under the Results leaf and set the output format, as shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: ...or Query -> Results To -> Results To File or Right Click in the query editor and select Results To -> Results To File